# EF Core on SaveChanges keeps adding a record to a second table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating a tire storage scheduler and have all the storage information stored in the database. When finalizing the booking process, instead of just adding the record to the `tblSchedule` table, it also adds a duplicate of the customers data and stores it into the `tblStorageData` table just with a different ID which is set as an identity column.

This is my Schedule model:

```
[Table("tblSchedule")]
public class Schedule
{
        [Required]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public DateTime ScheduleDateTime { get; set; }

        public bool Confirmed { get; set; } = false;

        public StorageData StorageDataInfo { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `StorageData` model:

```
[Table("tblStorageData")]
public class StorageData
{
        [Required]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "License plate is required to perform search.")]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string LicensePlate { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10)]
        public string BIN { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `AddSchedule` method which takes the information and adds it to the database:

```
public int AddSchedule(Schedule model)
{
    if (CheckSchedule(model.ScheduleDateTime) >= 4)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        Schedule sch = new Schedule()
                {
                    ScheduleDateTime = model.ScheduleDateTime,
                    StorageDataInfo = model.StorageDataInfo
                };

        _context.Schedule.Add(sch);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return 1;
    }
}
```

This is my schedule controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Book(string id)
{
    string session = HttpContext.Session.GetString("CustomerVerify");
    string customerBooking = HttpContext.Session.GetString("CustomerBooking");

    if (session == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customer");
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Month", "Schedule");
    }

    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(id, "yyyyMMddHHmmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    FullBookingViewModel fbvm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FullBookingViewModel>(customerBooking);

    Schedule sch = new Schedule();
    sch.ScheduleDateTime = dt;
    sch.StorageDataInfo = fbvm.StorageDataInfo;

    return View(sch);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Book(Schedule model)
{
     Schedule sch = new Schedule()
            {
                StorageDataInfo = model.StorageDataInfo,
                ScheduleDateTime = model.ScheduleDateTime,
            };

     int result = _scheduleData.AddSchedule(model);

     if (result == 0)
     {
         return RedirectToAction("Day", "Schedule");
     }
     else
     {
         return RedirectToAction("Month", "Schedule");
     }
}
```

This is the cshtml view:

```
@model Schedule

<h1>Schedule.Book</h1>

<p>Please review the following appointment before confirming:</p>

@*@Model.ScheduleDateTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm tt")
<br />
@Model.StorageDataInfo.Name @Model.StorageDataInfo.LicensePlate @Model.StorageDataInfo.BIN
<br />*@

<form method="post">
    <label asp-for="@Model.ScheduleDateTime">@Model.ScheduleDateTime</label><br />
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ScheduleDateTime)

    <label asp-for="@Model.StorageDataInfo.Name">@Model.StorageDataInfo.Name</label>
    <label asp-for="@Model.StorageDataInfo.LicensePlate">@Model.StorageDataInfo.LicensePlate</label>
    <label asp-for="@Model.StorageDataInfo.BIN">@Model.StorageDataInfo.BIN</label><br />
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.StorageDataInfo.Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.StorageDataInfo.LicensePlate)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.StorageDataInfo.BIN)

    <button type="submit">Confirm</button>
    <button>Cancel</button>
    <button>Select Different Month</button>
    <button>Select Different Day</button>
    <button>Select Different Time</button>
</form>
```

[this is a screenshot of the tblSchedule table with the properly added times but the StorageDataInfoID should be the same all the way through.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtDg9.png)

[this is the screenshot of the tblStorageData table with the duplicate information also being added.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQezU.png)

I can't figure out why its adding to both tables when it should only be adding to the one table referencing the ID of the tblStorageData table and not duplicating the customer's information.

Answer (score 1):

It does this because when EF works with navigation properties, references are everything. If a DbContext is not tracking the instance of an entity it will treat that entity as a new instance, regardless of whether the entity has an ID or not.

The initial solution is to tell the DbContext to track the provided StorageData instance, and assume that the record exists:

```
public int AddSchedule(Schedule model)
{
    if (CheckSchedule(model.ScheduleDateTime) >= 4)
        return 0;

    _context.Attach(model.StorageDataInfo);

    _context.Schedule.Add(model);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return 1;
}
```

When server methods accept "entities" as parameters, you're not actually getting back an entity, but rather an entity class populated by the deserialized data provided by the client. You don't need to create new instances each time, however you also need to be careful when performing things like Updates to validate any data passed in from the client as it is possible to have been tampered with. Attaching entities can still lead to errors in operations where the DbContext is already tracking another instance for the same ID. The safer version of the above method would be:

```
public int AddSchedule(Schedule model)
{
    if (CheckSchedule(model.ScheduleDateTime) >= 4)
        return 0;

    var existingStorageData = _context.StorageData.Local
        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == model.StorageDataInfo.ID);
    if(storageData == null)
        _context.Attach(model.StorageDataInfo);
    else
        model.StorageDataInfo = existingStorageData

    _context.Schedule.Add(model);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return 1;
}
```

What this does is check the DbContext local cache (without hitting the DB) to return any tracked instance with that ID. If no instance is returned, we can attach the passed in copy, otherwise we replace the reference with the tracked instance.